# tableview data repeat when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I use a custom cell to show the `placeholder` but scrolling the table repeats the `placeholder`

```swift
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! AddTableViewCell

    cell.textInfo.delegate = self
    if textPlaceHolders![indexPath.row].containsString("Category") == true {
        cell.selected = true
        cell.textInfo.text = textPlaceHolders![indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    } else {
        cell.textInfo.placeholder = textPlaceHolders![indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

I tried some solution like this the problem resolved but when user end edit the text disappear

```
class AddTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var textInfo: UITextField!

  override func prepareForReuse() {
     textInfo.text= ""
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you assign `text` property for cell's `textInfo` outlet in one case and `placeholder` in another. Because of `UITableView`'s reuse policy your `textInfo` contains placeholder/text even if you haven't specified it for concrete `indexPath`. So you need to clean it up for every `indexPath` if you don't want them. Like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! AddTableViewCell
    cell.textInfo.delegate = self
    if textPlaceHolders![indexPath.row].containsString("Category") == true {
        cell.selected = true
        cell.textInfo.text = textPlaceHolders![indexPath.row]
        cell.textInfo.placeholder = nil
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    } else {
        cell.textInfo.placeholder = textPlaceHolders![indexPath.row]
        cell.textInfo.text = nil
    }
    return cell
}
```